# "Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string" error when calling a bash script from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I have a situation where, I need to call a bash script inside a python script which is in turn called inside another python script.

download-output-files.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

for i in node_path:
    cmd="python watcher.py "+i
    os.system(cmd) ##calling another python script
```

watcher.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import time

        if 'finish' in child:
            print "finish found"
        cmd="./copy_output_file.sh "+node   
        os.system(cmd) ##Calling shell script here
```

copy_output_file.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

filepath=$1
cp ff /home/likewise-open/TALENTICA-ALL/mayankp/kazoo/$filepath
```

When I run **download-output-files.py** , it calls **watcher.py** , which in turn calls **copy_output_file.sh** and below is the error I face:

```
mayankp@mayankp:~/kazoo$ python download-output-files.py 

finish found
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

When I run the same commands in Python shell, it runs bash script successfully. What am I missing?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it's caused by the unquoted variables in the shell script. But *why* are you using a shell script for something that could easily be done with Python?!

Comment: This seems like way too much code for this question. Will retract my close vote if you can trim it down to a minimal example.

Comment: @ChrisMartin, I've edited my code keeping minimal code. Could you please help now?

Comment: @Biffen, What do you mean when you say unquoted variables in shell script? I want to copy a file to another server, hence I wanted to use scp. In the code above, it's just a sample bash script. 

I have no clue how to copy a file to another server in Python.

Comment: @MayankPorwal `filepath=$1` should be `filepath="$1"`, etc. http://www.shellcheck.net is a great tool for checking such things.

Comment: The error message does not come from your script, because it is sh which complains, not bash. I guess the content of your variable `node` is the culprit. Print the content of `cmd` just before calling `os.system`.

Comment: @user1934428: you are right..! It was the problem! thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's generally unwise to concatenate strings into shell commands. Try inserting `print(cmd)` before your `os.system(cmd)` calls to find out exactly what commands you're trying to run, and I supect you'll notice what the problem is (likely a file name with an apostrophe in it).

Try using `subprocess.call(['python', 'watcher.py', i])` instead of `os.system("python watcher.py "+i)`, and `subprocess.call(['/copy_output_file.sh', node])` instead of `os.system(cmd="./copy_output_file.sh "+node)`.

Comment: I inserted a print(cmd) before os.system(cmd) and it worked. Thanks